# How to properly run eclipse hawkBit

Tags: linux, docker, eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I am new to the tech world, I want to get to know eclipse hawkBit, I am a total noob and beginner so any help is mucha appreciated.

My scenario:
I have a Windows 10 OS with VMware workstation on it, I have installed Ubuntu on it to run eclipse hawkBit and docker ofcourse.
My internet connection is a highspeed mobile internet connection, I use my smarphone to tether(Mobile hotspot).

What I want to do:
I want to start eclipse hawkBit so basically run it simulate some devices and get to know how to use hawkBit.

My problem: so to run hawkBit according to the official documentation i just need to give this on the terminal: `docker run -p 8080:8080 hawkbit/hawkbit-update-server:latest`

I have seen a youtube video where if hawkBit works it will show me the localhost port info and say successfully connected(or something similar to that)
but the error or problem i keep encountering is this: `2021-06-17 11:35:19.312  INFO 1 --- [tContainer#1-56] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]`

Here is a picture of it: [image: Error in Terminal window]

I would really appreciate if you guys could help me with this, there is not much support or videos of this problem, infact its hard to find decent reference material for hawkBit.
any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you see here is due to a missing (or misconfigured) RabbitMQ service.

You will need to configure the environment variable `SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST` to point to the running RabbitMQ instance.

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -e SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=ip-of-rabbitmq-service hawkbit/hawkbit-update-server:latest`

For an easier setup, you could use [the docker compose file for hawkbit](https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/tree/master/hawkbit-runtime/docker) (Option B or C), which already has a preconfigured RabbitMQ as well as MySQL container.